# Replace file line with multi-line, special char string

Tags: bash, sed, markdown

I'm trying to automate generating a `README.md`.

The idea is:

1. Generate markdown table string like...

   ```sh
   table="| Image | Name | Description | Notes |\n"
   table+="| --- | --- | --- | --- |\n"
   table+="| $img1 | $name1 | $desc1 | $notes1 |\n"
   table+="| $img2 | $name2 | $desc2 | $notes2 |\n"
   ...
   ```

   <sub>*simplified</sub>

   *contains special characters like e.g. `|-()[]/<>`
2. Replace `<!-- insert-table-here -->` in a `readme_template.md` file with the full table

   ```
   ## Header

   <!-- insert-table-here -->

   <sub>More info...</sub>
   ```
3. Save new file as `README.md`

I can't get step 2 working.

**How do you replace a line in a file with a multi-line, special char ridden string?**

Every `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, or even `head/tail` command I try seems to not work. Are `heredocs` the better approach?

I have found some hack solutions for specific cases with specific chars but I want to identify a more robust method.

EDIT: Thanks to @potong, this is what ended up working for me.

```
echo -e ${table} | sed -e '/<!-- insert-table-here -->/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' readme_template.md > README.md
```

EDIT 2: After spending some more time on this, I found a nice multi-match option through `awk`

```
awk \
  -v t1="$(generate_table1)" \
  -v t2="$(generate_table2)" \
  '{
    gsub(/<!-- insert-table-1 -->/,t1)
    gsub(/<!-- insert-table-2 -->/,t2)
  }1' \
  readme_template.md > README.md
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -e '/<!-- insert-table-here -->/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file
Here is a heredoc
with special symbols
{}-()[]/<>
!
```

The heredoc is piped through to the sed command using `/dev/stdin` as a file for the `r` command, then the original line is deleted using the `d` command.

N.B. The use of the `-e` command line option to split the two parts of the sed script (oneliner). This is necessary because the `r` command needs to be terminated by a newline and the `-e` option provides this functionality.

Comment: It's often difficult to tell with `sed`, but I believe this is portable (eg, doesn't require gnu sed).  You may need to omit the space between `r` and `/dev/stdin`, or (I suspect) some versions may try to read from a file that has a leading space in its name.

Comment: Thank you @potong. I'll give this a try soon and accept once I can confirm.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I would love to remove the caveat but know in all honesty that it does not go far enough.

Comment: @rowboat  It's interesting that the leading blanks are allowed.  How can one reference a file whose name begins with a space?  It's almost as if  allowing whitespace in filenames was a bad idea :).

Comment: These lines worked as expected!

`$ echo -e ${container_table} | sed -e '/<!-- insert-container-table -->/{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' readme_template.md > README.md`


`$ echo -e ${container_table} | sed -e '/<!-- insert-container-table -->/{r/dev/stdin' -e 'd}' readme_template.md > README.md`